# Primary key doesn't match checkbox [] array row number for deletion in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Can someone please help me get this code to either renumber the primary key $idfilm back to a consecutive order after deletion of a row?   when I delete all the data in the table the primary key that's set to auto_increment, it starts at the last number it left off.

I'm guessing this is normal since its a unique key.  If so then how do I get my $_POST['checkbox'] to equal the same unique row number so that I can "DELETE mytable where $_POST['checkbox'] = the unique key row?

Keep in mind thar $id_actor is a foreign key to another table.

```
$row_number = 1;
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

$id_actor= $row["id_actor"];
$idfilm= $row["idfilm"]; 
$filmTitle= $row["filmTitle"];
$filmRole= $row["filmRole"];
$filmDirector= $row["filmDirector"];


echo"<tr>";
echo '<td><input name="checkbox[]" value="$idfilm'.$row_number.'" type="checkbox" 
id="checkbox'.$row_number.'" /></td>';


for ($i=0; $i<5; $i++)  {
   echo"<td> $row[$i]</td>";
}
echo"</tr>";

$row_number++;
}
echo"</table>";
```

.......................................................................................

Here's my delete code that doesn't delete anything because $del_id does not match $idfilm.

```
if(isset($_POST['delete'])) {
if(array_key_exists('checkbox',$_POST)) {  
foreach ($_POST['checkbox'] as $del_id) {
echo $del_id;  
$sql = "DELETE FROM filmInfo WHERE 'idfilm' = '$del_id' "; //This line needs work
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error()); 
if(mysql_affected_rows($result)) echo 'Selected data rows Deleted';
}
}

}
```

Comment: `AUTO_INCREMENT` is intended to guarantee _uniqueness_, it is _not_ intended to guarantee sequentiality.

Comment: Instead of incrementing `$row_number` supply a value with the checkbox which uniquely identifies it - for that, its auto-increment id should do just fine.

Comment: ... don't forget to validate the contents of `$del_id` to be the format you expect (int, for example), otherwise this is vulnerable to SQL injection and trivial deletion of _all_ your rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the only change you need to handle this is:

CHANGE `value="$idfilm'.$row_number.'"`

TO `value="'.$idfilm.'"`

Unnecessarily adding an overload of manipulating all rows (for id change) in db table is not recommended.

Answer (score 0):

I would just let MySQL do this for you. Try reordering with this after your delete row:

```
SET @count = 0;
UPDATE `users` SET `users`.`ID` = @count:= @count + 1;
```

Then you can update the AUTO_INCREMENT value to the max ID of the original table:

```
ALTER TABLE `users` AUTO_INCREMENT = (SELECT MAX(`users`.`ID`) FROM `users`);
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Your query should be like

`$sql = "DELETE FROM filmInfo WHERE idfilm = '$del_id' ";`